# How to flag duplicate rows in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I got this dataframe and would like to add a column that indicates if a client_id exists more than onces.

```
client     age-group     category
1       <18           basic
1       <18           premium
2       <18           premium
3       <18           premium
4       18-24           basic
5       18-24           basic
6       <18           basic
5       <18           premium
2       <18           basic
7       <18           basic
```

to:

```
client     age-group     category      regular_client
1       <18           basic            yes
1       <18           premium          yes
2       <18           premium          yes
3       <18           premium          no
4       18-24           basic          no
5       18-24           basic          yes
6       <18           basic            no
5       <18           premium          yes
2       <18           basic            yes
7       <18           basic            no
```

The only approach I know is by

```
for idx, _ in df.iterrows():
```

But I'm pretty sure there is a faster and easier possibility.

Answer (score 2):

Use `Series.duplicated` + `Series.map`:

```
df['regular_client'] = df['client'].duplicated(keep=False).map({True:'yes', False:'no'})
```

OR `Series.duplicated` + `np.where`,

```
df['regular_client'] = np.where(df['client'].duplicated(keep=False), 'yes', 'no')
```

Result:

```
   client age-group category regular_client
0       1       <18    basic            yes
1       1       <18  premium            yes
2       2       <18  premium            yes
3       3       <18  premium             no
4       4     18-24    basic             no
5       5     18-24    basic            yes
6       6       <18    basic             no
7       5       <18  premium            yes
8       2       <18    basic            yes
9       7       <18    basic             no
```

Answer (score 2):

`df.iterrows()` is not a good solution, because then you have access only to the current row, whereas you need to check whether there are more rows with whe same *client*.

Use:

```
df['regular_client'] = np.where(df.duplicated(subset=['client'], keep=False), 'yes', 'no')
```

Answer (score 0):

Just count occurrences of client:

```
df['regular_client'] = df.groupby('x')['x'].transform('count').gt(1).map({True: 'Yes', False: 'No'})
```

When count is greater than 1 then client is regular.